# How to get specific result from my IntlDateFormatter() function.?

Tags: php, function, datetime-format

i have this function to convert gregorian date to Jalali(Persian) date :

```
function toJalali ($date)
{
  $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter("fa_IR@calendar=persian", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Tehran', IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);
  return $fmt->format($date);
}
```

when i call it `toJalali(time())` it's give me full date `(1397-8-17 ه.ش ...)`

how do i get my specific date format from above function.?

i know that format options can be set in constructor :

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter("fa_IR@calendar=persian", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Tehran', IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

but what about when i want other time formats.?

like only `year : (yyyy)` or `(EEEE/yyyy/MM)` or etc. so i must write individual function for each date format.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the pattern you can use [setPattern](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.setpattern.php) method like this:

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter("fa_IR@calendar=persian", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Tehran', IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
$fmt->setPattern('EEEE/yyyy/MM');
echo  $fmt->format(0);
```

And your function would be look like this:

```
function toJalali ($date, $pattern = null)
{
  $fmt = new IntlDateFormatter("fa_IR@calendar=persian", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Tehran', IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);
  if ($pattern){
     $fmt->setPattern($pattern);
  }

  return $fmt->format($date);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but what's your suggestion to keep the function.?

Comment: @MehdiBoveiri check the answer again